website icon isn't showing on the desktop shortcut
I have a website that adds a certain favicon directly from session, when i add it as a shortcut the icon doesn't show.
I tried commenting out a code that adds it statically and it did work, the shortcut showed the icon, this is the code:
  <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../app-assets/images/ico/favicon.ico"> -->

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="../../images/<?php echo $_SESSION['profile']['tenant_logo_uuid']; ?>">

can someone please help?

Which version works? The one with the static URL or the one that uses $_SESSION?

rel="shortcut icon" is not standard and you shouldn't use it.

Which desktop are you talking about? OS-X, Linux, Windows, other?

I'm guessing that "adding it as a shortcut" probably means the desktop manager itself makes a request for the URL you are adding - and then of course there will be no existing session, because that only exists in your browser.

Either that - or it might only like image/x-icon, but not the image/icon you are adding instead.

Please note that rel="shortcut icon" is not standard (as commented above), so please do not use it.
To create favicon , including short-cut icons for smartphones / tablets, you should include in your site:
a) a favicon.png (size:16X16)
b) a number of icons with different sizes so that they fit into the smartphone and tablets of various sizes (see below)
<link rel="icon" href="https://www.yoursite.com/favicon.png"> 


<link href="https://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-57X57.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" />
<link href="https://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" />
<link href="https://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" />
<link href="https://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" />
<link href="https://www.yoursite.com/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" />
<link href="https://www.yoursite.com/icon-hires.png" rel="icon" sizes="192x192" />
<link href="https://www.yoursite.com/icon-normal.png" rel="icon" sizes="128x128" />


Just make sure that you replace the above icons with the ones you want if you want to generate them thru session variables.
Now for your case, assuming that the session variables such as <?php echo $_SESSION['profile']['tenant_logo_uuid']; ?> as in your line below does generate a valid favicon file:
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/icon" href="../../images/<?php echo $_SESSION['profile']['tenant_logo_uuid']; ?>">

In that case, amend the favicon lines as in my suggested answer and advise the user to create the desktop shortcuts of the site AFTER he/she has logged in the site -- then it should work
In my experience the smartphone / tablet desktop icons always persist even the user rebooted his/her device and not get connected yet. (due to caching)

This answer does not address the problem encountered in the question.

But I think my last line has already hightlighted this ?

No it is not. See comment made by CBroe: "I'm guessing that "adding it as a shortcut" probably means the desktop manager itself makes a request for the URL you are adding - and then of course there will be no existing session, because that only exists in your browser."

Then again, we cannot be sure about this. We don't know which desktop it is. The question is vague and Georgio Hayek doesn't respond to inquiries.
